# Extract table from PDF in UiPath Studio

Tags: pdf, uipath

I have 2 sets of PDFs like below

[image: First PDF]
[image: Second PDF]
The column changed for every pdf, I checked with document understanding, read pdf text, read pdf text with ocr and screen scrapping not working properly.

For using read pdf text, i got the output below

[image: read pdf text output]

I need to get the table with spaces(emplty cells), how can i get this?

Answer (score 0):

There are tools & APIs available that offer swift PDF data extraction to Excel. Some of them are integrated with UiPath which opens a wider range of activities that can be performed.

UiPath integrations can be easily set up to extract data automatically. They can also merge with other integrations for a more sophisticated task.

Here’s a tutorial explaining how to extract PDF data using UiPath integration. That is how you can either extract a single PDF document or choose a few pages or even a specific area in the PDF file. The output can be done in Excel or CSV with further configurations available.

Find a more detailed explanation below.

How to Convert PDF to CSV with UiPath - PDF.co
Learn how you can convert PDF to CSV with UiPath and PDF.co extension. Check out the detailed tutorial and video demos.
https://pdf.co/pdf-to-csv-with-uipath

Comment: I will check with this

Comment: PDF.co extension is not working in uipath studio, suggest any other methods